# Three.js: What is the meshPerAttribute argument in an InstancedBufferAttribute

Tags: three.js, webgl

I'm confused about the argument `meshPerAttribute` in a Three.js `InstancedBufferAttribute` [[docs](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/core/InstancedBufferAttribute.meshPerAttribute)]. What does the `meshPerAttribute` argument set? I've only seen the value 1 provided as an argument to this--why is that, and what does this argument do?

If someone can help me understand this, I'd be happy to translate your comment into a pull request to update the docs, which don't gloss this argument as far as I can see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It just means how often a value in the attribute array is used for drawing instances. A value of one means, a single attribute value is used for one instanced mesh. A value of two means, a single attribute value is used for two instanced meshes.

`meshPerAttribute` is directly mapped to the `divisor` parameter of `vertexAttribDivisorANGLE()`. More information here:

https://blog.tojicode.com/2013/07/webgl-instancing-with.html

Comment: @Mungen87 thanks very much, this helps. I thought the itemSize argument was somehow also indicating how many values in an array belong to each instance -- if you have a moment could I please ask you for advice on differentiating the `itemSize` and `meshPerAttribute` arguments? Any help you can offer would be great!

Comment: `meshPerAttribute` is only related to instanced rendering whereas `itemSize` is a property of all buffer attributes. Anything else should actually be explained in the documentation of `three.js` (https://threejs.org/docs/#api/core/BufferAttribute) and the linked article. TBH, I don't know what else to say about this topic.